# Creating a generic ObservableItem Class

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I would like to create a generic ObservableItem class, and I would like to get an ideas on how to implement it.
I would like it to be generic so that i could use it with all types of types (if its possible).
The reason I want to create it is to be able to bind multiple controls to an array, instead of creating properties for each bind. (I want a two way binding, so that when the source gets updated, the control will be notified with PropertyChanged event).
I started to create the class, but I don't know what implementation to add in order to make it generic for every type use.

```
public struct ObservableItem<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private T _item;
    private T Item
    {
        get {

            return _item; 
        }
        set
        {
            _item = value;
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_item.ToString()));
        }
    }


    public static implicit operator T(ObservableItem<T> value)
    {
        return value.Item;
    }

    public static implicit operator ObservableItem<T>(T value)
    {
        var ret = new ObservableItem<T>();
        ret.Item = value;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

The uses i would like to have with the class suppose to be suitable for everything:

```
ObservableItem<int> value1 = 5;
ObservableItem<int>[] aValue = new ObservableItem<int>[5];
aValue[0] = 4;
aValue[1] = 5;
aValue[2] = aValue[0] + aValue[1];
aValue[3] = aValue[0] * aValue[1];

ObservableItem<bool> value2;
value2 = !value2;

ObservableItem<bool>[] Channels = new ObservableItem<bool>[4];
// and more uses
```

Xaml Binding:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Channels[0]}" Content="Channel 1" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Channels[1]}" Content="Channel 2" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Channels[2]}" Content="Channel 3" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Channels[3]}" Content="Channel 4" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` must be passed the property na,e.

Comment: Because SLaks missed the 5 minute edit window: `PropertyChanged` must be passed the property *name*.

Comment: The `if (_item == null) _item = default(T);` line doesn't make sense.  If `T` is a value type then `_item == null` will be false.  If `T` is a reference type then `default(T)` will be `null`.

Comment: About the propertyName i'll think of something (any advice would be accepted) but this is not my main problem. About the the lazy instantiation I fixed it

Comment: While a interesting project your question is too overly broad for Stack Overflows Q&A format. Can you narrow down your question more specifically about what is blocking you? Perhaps try to make it generic and which you get stuck implementing it ask a question specifically on how to implement that one part.

Comment: I think it is a really bad practice to create an event in a struct. It totally does not make sense.

Comment: What do your bindings look like in XAML? I can't see this actually being very useful.

Comment: This isn't the best way to go about things.  Optimal choice would be to magically imbue POCO objects with update notifications, but that also allowed support for other UI-centric paradigms, like undo/redo, attached properties, etc.  Such a thing actually exists in the framework already, but it is designed around WF4 designers--the ModelItem http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities.Presentation/System.Activities.Presentation/System/Activities/Presentation/Model/ModelItemImpl.cs,ed2557c0fd0e2be5 it's not too hard to create a stripped down version. Works seamlessly.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, in my example of using the class, i explained the general use of the class. basically, i would like the same uses regular types would have for easy manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that solves my problem, so i'm posting it as an answer for everybody to use.

I didn't found a way to create a generic ObservableItem that would allow me to use it as every object. like:

```
public ObservableItem<bool> value {get;set}
```

And in xaml to bind directly to 'value' rather than 'value.Item'.
Also whenever i would change the value with implicit operator the binding stops.

```
value = !value; //kills the binding - because the object is replaced
```

So, i wrote an ObservableItemCollection that inherits ObservableCollection and reimplement the indexer operator of ObservableCollection's base the Collection, so that every set operation will call the PropertyChanged event handler.

```
public class ObservableItemCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private string propertyName;

    public ObservableItemCollection(string propertyName, int numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd = 0)
        : base()
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.AddDefaults(numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd);
    }
    public ObservableItemCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection, string propertyName, int numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd = 0)
        : base(collection)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.AddDefaults(numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd);
    }
    public ObservableItemCollection(List<T> list, string propertyName, int numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd = 0)
        : base(list)
    {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
        this.AddDefaults(numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd);
    }


    public new T this[int index]
    {
        get { return base[index]; }
        set
        {
            base[index] = value;
            // Call ObservableCollection OnPropertyChanged method.
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public void AddDefaults(int numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd = 1)
    {
        if (numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numberOfItemsToAdd must be a non-negative number");
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDefaultItemsToAdd; ++i)
            base.Add(default(T));
    }
}
```

That way i can use the collection like any class array, and bind to the item directly.

```
public ObservableItemCollection<bool> Channels { get; set; }
```

And in xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Channels[0]}" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Content="Channel 2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Channels[1]}" Style="{StaticResource Channels}"></CheckBox>
</StackPanel>
```

>